# Filter three or more criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I need to filter on the same column using 3+ criteria.

Somebody has already suggested this:

```
Sub FiltInvoices()

    Range("B6:N9000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array("C2", "D2", "E2"), _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

However, I want to actually reference the cells C2, D2, E2 rather than for the text "C2" "D2" "E2".

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to find ? Are you wanting to filter the columns C, D, and E?

Comment: I want to find the same values in column 2 as is in the cells C2 or D2 or E2. These 3 cells change depending on user input though

Comment: Try: `Criteria1:=Array(Range("C2").Value, Range("D2").Value, Range("E2").Value)`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much Rory.

Comment: Rory, (or anyone else who can assist)...the code was working a few days ago, however now seems to only return the final value in the list. So JUST E2 for example.

Comment: Code reads as follows: 'Sub FilterInvoices()

Range("B6:N9000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array(Range("C2").Value, Range("D2").Value, Range("E2").Value)

End Sub'